# Div Scroll With a page not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

So, I set my div to

```
 position:fixed;
```

to have it scroll with the page, but now it is not centered correctly, it's off in the top left corner. Here's the whole div code below: (note, without position:fixed; it centered fine before)

```
 #menu {
  width: 70%;
  padding:10px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#CCCC00;
  border-width:5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:white;
  color:black; 
  font-family: Poor Richard;
  font-size:23px; 
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
 }
```

My question is, how do you make a div scroll with the page, but stay centered?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the `top` and `left` properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**used to this**  `css`  define your `#menu` `left:50%;` **and** `margin-left : -35%` `// total width of #menu /2;`

**as like this**

```
    #menu {
      width: 70%;
      padding:10px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-color:#CCCC00;
      border-width:5px;
      border-radius: 10px;
     left:50%;  // _______________________ add this 
      margin-left:-35%;   // _______________________ add this  
      background-color:white;
      color:black; 
      font-family: Poor Richard;
      font-size:23px; 
      text-align: center;
      position: fixed;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;    // _______________________ add this 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;   // _______________________ add this 
    box-sizing:border-box;    // _______________________ add this 
     }
```

**and define** `box-sizing : border-box;`
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GuW46/1/)**

**[box-sizing more info](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

Comment: This works well thanks, but why do I need to define box-sizing and border-box?

Answer (score 0):

making `position:default` also solves your bug